# C++ protecting a private char * of a class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, private-members

I understand the differences of inheritance of public, private, protected with respect to class method / property constucts.  However, my question is specifically associated with pointers to null terminated strings..

```
class MyClass
{
   private: 
      char * SomeValue;

   ...
   ...
}
```

Now, somewhere through processing, the MyClass->SomeValue gets allocated and populated with a string value.  No problem.  Now, I want some calling source that has an instance of my "MyClass" object created and needs the string value from this.  Since C++ can do lots of damage with pointers, and pointers to pointers etc,  I want to return the pointer location to the string of chars allocated, but don't want anyone to change values.  Is this default controlled inside the compiler and memory management?  Its a low risk that anyone would be using this class as its primarily for internal purposes, but just more of my understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would return a const pointer to the chars. There is nothing that can stop someone casting the return value to a non const. But C++ isn't designed to defend against malicious coding.

```
class MyClass {
  char* someValue;
public:
  const char* get_SafeSomeValue() const {
    return someValue;
  }
};
```

Comment: Just for the record:  You should make `get_SafeSomeValue` a const member function as well.

Comment: So the "const" modifier forces the protection level?  Thanks... that appears to be the consensus of answers under my circumstances.

Comment: no, you still can call `delete myClassInstance->get_SafeSomeValue();` and compiler won't tell you nothing.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't really do that.

Even if you do something like other people are suggesting, for example:

```
class MyClass {
    char* someValue;
public:
    const char* get_SafeSomeValue() const {
        return someValue;
    }
};
```

You still can invoke `delete myClassInstance->get_SafeSomeValue()`.

Comment: I have maliciously added a `const` to qualify the method, feel free to remove it if you're offended :)

Comment: No problem, the outcome is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a naked pointer to hold a string in C++ when `std::string` provides a cleaner, safer method of containing and transporting a string around?  What you want to do, it sounds like, is get at the string's value without allowing another class/function/method to change the value?  Just return it with `const` as a modifier:

```
const char* foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
private:
    const string someValue;
public:
    const string& getReadOnlyValue() { return someValue;};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
      const char * getValue(); // return a pointer to a const char that can't be modified
   private: 
      char * SomeValue;

   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't users to change the data that they point to you can have functions that return const char *.

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    char * SomeValue;


  public:
    const char * getSomeValue() const
    {
       return SomeValue;
    }
};
```

You need to be careful about objects of your class being copied and assigned. For practical purposes you might want to replace your char* with a std::string or std::vector< char>. Failing that you can either:

- Make your copy-constructor and assignment operator private and not implement them.
- Overload them to work properly.
- Derive from boost::noncopyable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. c++ provides no mechanism to prevent people from shooting themselves in foot. For example, how would you prevent someone from calling delete on that pointer?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - its just os-dependent to implement.

These things are handled via protected memory pages - you can allocate several memory pages and set them to eg. "read-only" - every write access will then fail with an exception. It just needs a little programmatical overhead.

In WindowsAPI VirtualAllocEx is a good starter...